# I keep having the same data row printed as an output event when I settled a range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk, google-colaboratory

Basically the title.
I'm relearning NLP and tried to use some data I found on Kaggle to make some "cheat-sheet", however, I've been into an odyssey to covert into a string and tokenize the "Review" column correctly to then remove stop words.
If I display the variables I settled for every thing I keep getting the same review row, even when I settled the entire range of the data.

[This is the code on Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AW26r_KcXuQL5C-a1lOWLX-7T3baNE3a?usp=sharing)

Comments are activated in the notebook so feel free to add your tips.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any relevant code and other information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link to external locations of source code or data.  Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def filterstop(row):
    return [word for word in word_tokenize(row) if word not in vacias]
```

Then apply that on the column.

Demostration:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'reviews':['the first sent', 'second sent', 'it is the third sent', 'fourth sent']})
vacias = stopwords.words('english')

def filterstop(row):
    return [word for word in word_tokenize(row) if word not in vacias]
data['tokenized reviews'] = data['reviews'].apply(filterstop)
data['tokenized reviews'].head(3)
```

Output:

```
0     [first, sent]
1    [second, sent]
2     [third, sent]
Name: tokenized reviews, dtype: object
```

Comment: It was very helpful, until I tried to display the range of reviews (I wanted to see the 7 first rows and it didn't work. Am i doing something wrong? Here are some pics https://imgur.com/a/4V0bfII

Comment: Use data['reviews'].head(7).

Comment: Did your problem solve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I couldn't. I made a new notebook just for code and with more specified things using "#" (In Spanish as well, sorry about that, but some are in english).

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15Eo-9vk8xbr1nW3A_CCymWKMYSMypCVu?usp=sharing Here's the new notebook, I also added some different trials

Comment: You have assigned some number to data and the variable has changed during running your notebook. Look at the answer again.

Comment: Does dataframe add numbers? Sorry, this may be an ingnorant comment but I don't see I have added any number other than the one I wanted to use for seeing the rows

Comment: I can not run your colab because date is on your drive. Currently there is no one but it is possible that when you tried there was and you removed that later.